# Collapsing and Hiding static UITableViewCells of a UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have been though a ton of examples that show how to do a collapsable tableview but I cant find something that works with static cells. I have a couple cells that I made in IB that I would like to collapse if the section header is clicked but I cant figure out or understand how to do it. If anyone can tell me or point me to an example that does that, I would be grateful.

Here is an example of just one of the cells I have that would need to collapse:

[image]

Comment: not sure about your requirements check this https://github.com/serverdensity/ios-SDNestedTable may be helpful for you.

Comment: @Mr.Rudy This is kind of helpful but it is like every example I have came across. I have my cells already made in my Storyboard and dont know how change this example to work with the cells ive already made.

Comment: Sorry that will be tough one for me too .you should wait may be some expert help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution I was happy with thanks to this: https://github.com/xelvenone/StaticDataTableViewController

A very simple solution with the implementation:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.reloadTableViewRowAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle;
    self.deleteTableViewRowAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle;
    self.insertTableViewRowAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {


        [self toggleCellVissibilityOrReload:self.cell1];

        } 

        [self reloadDataAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: @MazenKasser `
- (void) toggleCellVissibilityOrReload:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    
    
    [self cell:cell setHidden:![self cellIsHidden:cell]];

    [self reloadDataAnimated:YES];
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this sample: (download the sample code)

> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

So basically what this code does is:

1. You create Section in your -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section  --> Each Section has SectionHeaderView --> Which you basically will tap and expand your table view.
2. You will implement the two delegate methods:

   - -(void)sectionHeaderView:(APLSectionHeaderView*)sectionHeaderView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)sectionOpened
   - -(void)sectionHeaderView:(APLSectionHeaderView*)sectionHeaderView sectionClosed:(NSInteger)sectionClosed

--> This will internally call insertRowsAtIndexPaths and deleteRowsAtIndexPaths --> Which will internally call tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath --> Now here you need to create your cell which will have address, city etc etc...

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Have you looked at the sample code they provide? It is very buggy, things dont work right and it will crash after collapsing and expanding some sections.

Comment: Yes I Agree, but you dont have to just copy and paste, do the right thing. It basically gives you a direction to start... We have used that code as reference, did the right thing and it works smooth... and non buggy